# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have just setup Intertia with Vue and laravel and I can't seem to get the pages to load I am having this error [image]

Here is the setup

`app.js`

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: async (name) => {
    const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')

    return (await pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]())
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

`IndexController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return inertia('Index/Index');
    }
    public function show(){
        return inertia('Index/Show');
    }
}
```

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/show', [IndexController::class, 'show']);
```

here is just some basic vue template
`Index.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>index</div>
</template>
```

I expect for the index.vue to be displayed just showing the simple text index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on "App" variable in a Inertia.js + Laravel + Typescript + Vue 3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583649/error-on-app-variable-in-a-inertia-js-laravel-typescript-vue-3-applicati)

Comment: Solved the issue I was doing wrong folder structure :) 
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue was having the Pages folder in the wrong folder
The pages folder should be in `resources/js/Pages`. My mistake was having the pages folder in `resources/js`

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was writing `.vue` in my path:

```
return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Admin/Home.vue'); // wrong
```

I removed .vue and problem solved

```
return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Admin/Home'); // correct
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it was due to case-sensitive directory naming on ubuntu. It was working fine locally on my PC but when deploying to the server it would fail. I had named the folder `/pages` not `/Pages`.